# How to delete existing tables in wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

Can I delete my existing database tables from wordpress database?

**Problem:**
When I open `website.com/wp-admin`. 
This error message is displaying

```
One or more database tables are unavailable. The database may need to be repaired.
```

And when I open my website this error message is displaying.

```
Error establishing a database connection
```

My username, password and host names are correct.

**Question:**
How can I delete existing tables and install new wordpress.

**Note** I have not access of hosting server. I have just wordpress admin access. and have database username and password.

If I click on repair.

These lines appear. These are 11 tables, but wordpress have 13 tables.

```
The wp_users table is okay.

The wp_usermeta table is okay.

The wp_posts table is okay.

The wp_comments table is okay.

The wp_links table is okay.

The wp_options table is okay.

The wp_postmeta table is okay.

The wp_terms table is okay.

The wp_term_taxonomy table is okay.

The wp_term_relationships table is okay.

The wp_commentmeta table is okay.

Repairs complete. Please remove the following line from wp-config.php to prevent this page from being used by unauthorized users.

define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achive that by using this plugin [SQL Executioner](http://wordpress.org/plugins/sql-executioner/).

After activating the plugin just go to "tools" menu in the admin panel, there you can find that, run the query you want there!

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you are not required to delete the tables, all you need is to repair your existing tables.

For that please go to your server database:

1>>Check all the tables, and choose the "repair table" option from the drop down list.

2>> Hit the go button, that's it!!

Hope that will help
```

Comment: I have not access server, I have just wordpress admin access

Answer (score 0):

You can not access database from wordpress admin panel.